# Problem changing page layout assigned to lightning page

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I can't seem to change the page layout associated with a lightning page.  I am using two record types and have created two page layouts and assigned them properly in the page assignment interface.  I have created two lightning pages and activated each by record type properly.  But for some reason, they both point to one page layout and I can't seem to change one of them.  In the attached screen shot, I need to link this one to the Student Schedule Layout.  Again, I have confirmed that this page is assigned to the proper Record Type.  Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: Follow-up...I saved the lightning page and created records and it works properly.  It was just a problem in the designer.  After creating records and going back into the designer it works fine.  Not sure if it is a cache problem or what.  All is good now.